# I want to add menu and score

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm a newbie here learning how to create a game in android and stumbled on a tutorial http://williammora.com/a-running-game-with-libgdx-part-1 
i already finished the game but it lacks menu and score. I am getting overwhelmed by the number of classes and i don't know where to put the menu screen. there is a `java` class there that is named Android Launcher and i think its the one that calls the game to start so I created a layout xml menu and try to call it after pressing a button this is my code. there's no error but the game crashes

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button next = findViewById(R.id.btnLetsgo);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
            initialize(new RollOut(), config);
        }
    });



 }
}
```

ive read some tutorials and its possible to create a layout for the menu. ill add another class Main.class and `public class Main extends AndroidApplication {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button next = findViewById(R.id.btnLetsgo);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            gotoNext();
        }
    });
}
private void gotoNext(){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, AndroidLauncher.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

}`

and the androidlauncher class 
`public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new RollOut(), config);
        Intent i = getIntent();
    }
}`
 but its still crashing

Comment: How can there be no error log if game crashes? check the dropdown where you are running the instance. Android studio opens a new instance, but you can still check older error logs.

Comment: Why not just create the menu and score in Libgdx? that should be kind of hard if you tried to manage two view codes (Android, Core), there is an elegant way to make a view in Libgdx and using xml by using [gdx-lml](https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-lml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds that maybe you are very new in libgdx. It very hard to say with you where should be puth your Menu Screen. Let spend your time to study Screen Class. Which you can extend to create you MenuScreen. Here is more information I hope useful for you: 
example: https://www.gamedevelopment.blog/full-libgdx-game-tutorial-menu-control/
wiki: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d

Comment: if Im going to create a menu using xml layout? where should i put the corresponding activity for it?
http://i64.tinypic.com/24wdd7l.png
http://tinypic.com/r/24wdd7l/9

Comment: Sorry friend, I have never use XML to create LIBGDX GUI. You mean that you will use android to create MENU. It is ok, because of Libgdx screen only a Android VIew. But It make you confuse in the future. Please try to make your menu by libgdx. If have any project, let me know, I will make some snipe code for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainScreen extends Screen{ public MainScreen{} }
```

And in game class:

```
this.setScreen(new MainScreen()) ;
```